# Java resize layout by resizing element

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I have a problem.

I have JFrame element.
Inside this frame element there's PaintingPanel (extends swing JPanel class) with layout set to `FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT)` and fixed width and height.
Inside PaintingPanel there's CanvasPanel element (extends JPanel class aswell).
CanvasPanel has layout set to GroupLayout (2x2). In the left top cell I have canvas element.
In other 3 cells I have resizers for canvas. Resizer extends JPanel class aswell.

When resizing canvas I want to resize CanvasPanel aswell with the (canvas) resizers. I also want the resizers to be fit the canvas dimension:

1. right, horizontal resizer should have width of 10px and height of canvas
2. bottom, vertical resizer should have width of canvas and height of 10px
3. bottom-right, (both horizontal and vertical) resizer should be 10px by 10px

I also don't want to resize PaintingPanel.

How can I acheive desired result?

This is the code of the layout in CanvasPanel:

```
private void setDefaultLayout()
{
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
    setLayout(layout);
    layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(canvas)
                .addComponent(resizers.get("middle-right")))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                .addComponent(resizers.get("bottom-middle"))
                .addComponent(resizers.get("bottom-right")))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(canvas)
                .addComponent(resizers.get("bottom-middle")))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(resizers.get("middle-right"))
                .addComponent(resizers.get("bottom-right")))
    );
}
```

This is the current method for resizing the CanvasPanel

```
public void resizeCanvas(int width, int height)
{
    this.width = width + 40;
    this.height = height + 40;
    setSize(width, height);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.width, this.height));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(this.width, this.height));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(this.width, this.height));
    canvas.setSize(width, height);
}
```

May anyone help?

Comment: Calling `pack()` on the top level container should do it.

Comment: Do you mean JFrame element? What if CanvasPanel is inserted inside other JPanel?

Comment: What's a `CanvasPanel`? What's a _canvas element_? What's a _resizer_? Maybe you could [edit] your question and post a [mcve]?

Comment: *"Do you mean JFrame element?"* Is there another component / window in the app. that has a `pack()` method? *"What if CanvasPanel is inserted inside other JPanel?"* .. what happened when you tried it?

Comment: I tried the scenario of nested JPanels, calling JFrame's `pack()` method (yes, it's the only elemnt 'above' the CanvasPanel which has `pack()` method). It hasn't done anything important. Now I try a different approach to solve this problem using layout null in CanvasPanel. Even PaintingPanel  (level above CanvasPanel) may be not necessary. If I'd acheive desired result, I'll post it here.

Comment: *"It hasn't done anything important."* It typically works just fine. Post an MRE (as linked in the comment of @Abra) of your attempt, so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: The code has changed and I haven't commited that one related to the problem, so I may have problem reproducing it 1:1. Now I'm working on different code using different approach. I'd just try to do some research and experiments by myself, because I feel that could be done much easier. If I'd solve this, I'll post the answer. If not, I'd post MRE of what I'd acheive.

Answer (score -1):

I've already found solution and I post it below.
I've done it by using `setLayout(null)` and `setBounds()` method.
Code isn't refactorized yet.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Launcher
{
    private int offsetX = 10, offsetY = 10;
    private HashMap<String, Res> resizers = new HashMap<String, Res>();
    private JFrame frame;
    private JScrollPane pane;
    private Canvas canvas;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Launcher l = new Launcher();
    l.create();
}

public void create()
{
    initFrame();

    int canvasWidth = 200;
    int canvasHeight = 200;

    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.setVisible(true);
    canvas.setBounds(offsetX, offsetY, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    canvas.repaint();

    resizers.put("horizontal", new Res(
            this,
            2*offsetX + canvasWidth,
            offsetY,
            Res.DEFAULT_WIDTH,
            canvasHeight
    ));
    resizers.put("vertical", new Res(
            this,
            offsetX,
            2*offsetY + canvasHeight,
            canvasWidth,
            Res.DEFAULT_WIDTH
    ));
    resizers.put("both", new Res(
            this,
            2*offsetX + canvasWidth,
            2*offsetY + canvasHeight,
            Res.DEFAULT_WIDTH,
            Res.DEFAULT_WIDTH
    ));

    pane = new JScrollPane();
    pane.setLayout(null);
    pane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    pane.add(canvas);
    pane.add(resizers.get("horizontal"));
    pane.add(resizers.get("vertical"));
    pane.add(resizers.get("both"));

    frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
}

public void resizeCanvasBy(int x, int y)
{
    int width = canvas.getWidth() + x;
    int height = canvas.getHeight() + y;
    canvas.setSize(width, height);
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    resizers.get("horizontal").setBounds(
            2*offsetX + width, offsetY, Res.DEFAULT_WIDTH, height);
    resizers.get("vertical").setBounds(
            offsetX, 2*offsetY + height, width, Res.DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    resizers.get("both").setBounds(
            2*offsetX + width, 2*offsetY + height, Res.DEFAULT_WIDTH, Res.DEFAULT_WIDTH);
}

public void initFrame()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setUndecorated(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public class Res extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 10;
    private Launcher launcher;
    private int pressedX, pressedY;

    public Res(Launcher launcher, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        this.launcher = launcher;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setVisible(true);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        pressedX = e.getX();
        pressedY = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int deltaX = e.getX() - pressedX;
        int deltaY = e.getY() - pressedY;
        launcher.resizeCanvasBy(deltaX, deltaY);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}

}
```